# Laravel redirect()->back() return me iframe

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

I am having problem in Laravel with redirect back.

I used this code for set lang to sessions:

```
   Route::get('/lang/{locale}', function ($locale){

    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
 
});
```

works fine.

But on several pages, I have used `iframe` with route inside:

```html
<iframe src="{{route('wizzard')}}" width="800px" height="650px">
</iframe>
```

**Problem**: Why does `->back()` return Route "wizzard" from `iframe` instead of the original page when there is `iframe`?

How can I make laravel ignore the `iframe` inside when it returns?

Comment: question for you ... how do you think it determines what 'back' is for the current request?

Answer (score 0):

i make URL check in route and now is ok...

```
    Route::get('/lang/{locale}', function (Request $request, $locale){

    Session::put('locale', $locale);

    $uri = str_replace(url('/'), '', url()->previous());

    if ($uri == '/wizzard'){
        return redirect('table');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
    
});
```